# Run NodeJS in Android

Tags: android, node.js, mobile, server, node-modules

I want to run NodeJS on Android and add some my node module to run specific function.

I tried https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore but it doesn't allow add 3rd module ( just allow sql or something in https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=liquidcore)
Most of library outdated.
How can i process it and which is the best library?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.